# Need Help in Convert Arrays of Objects into Single Array using Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to convert nested levels array of objects into a single array using a recursive function.

Below is my nested level json object that I need to convert into a single array

```
[{"CodiacSDK.NewModule.dll;extensionCreatePre;":[{"CodiacSDK.NewModule.dll;extensionExecutePost;":[{"CodiacSDK.PythonWrapper.dll;UnitValues::extensionInquirePre;":[]}]}]}]
```

I tried many recursive functions but none is working according to my requirement.

Like this one

```
function flatten(obj) {
var empty = true;
if (obj instanceof Array) {
    str = '[';
    empty = true;
    for (var i=0;i<obj.length;i++) {
        empty = false;
        str += flatten(obj[i])+', ';
    }
    return (empty?str:str.slice(0,-2))+']';
} else if (obj instanceof Object) {
    str = '{';
    empty = true;
    for (i in obj) {
        empty = false;
        str += i+'->'+flatten(obj[i])+', ';
    }
    return (empty?str:str.slice(0,-2))+'}';
} else {
    return obj; // not an obj, don't stringify me
}
```

}

My expected output is

```
["CodiacSDK.NewModule.dll;extensionCreatePre;", "CodiacSDK.NewModule.dll;extensionExecutePost;", "CodiacSDK.PythonWrapper.dll;UnitValues::extensionInquirePre;"];
```

Any help is really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) Show us what you tried; 2) Show us the expected output.

Comment: I've updated my question. please check.

Comment: please add the output as valid array/object.

Comment: I think those all should be the string, I've updated my output array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a recursive function for flattening the array of objects.

```js
function getFlat(array) {
    return array.reduce(
        (r, o) => Object.entries(o).reduce((p, [k, v]) => [k, ...getFlat(v)], r),
        []
    );
}

var data = [{ "CodiacSDK.NewModule.dll;extensionCreatePre;": [{ "CodiacSDK.NewModule.dll;extensionExecutePost;": [{ "CodiacSDK.PythonWrapper.dll;UnitValues::extensionInquirePre;": [] }] }] }]

console.log(getFlat(data));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Wow, that's great, perfectly working. Thank you very much.

Comment: Little problem, when I am using this code on client server, it shows this error : Uncaught TypeError: array.reduce is not a function, any suggestion what can be the issue here?

Comment: where are you running it?

Comment: Sorry, the server took time to update the code. Everything is fine now.